# What is the need to use a container like docker? Why couldn't we just have one or more dedicated machines to host services?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

I've entered market a few months ago. This week I started working in a new company, which uses Docker containers and Kubernetes to manage them.

I understand the concept of a container. But why to use containers over using just single or multiple machines for each service? I assume it would offer more performance and isolation. Is it because of costs issues that we don't do this?

Comment: Not an expert in the field but, it's all about moving services from machine to machine.  Docker containers _isolate_ services from one another, and Kubernetes is a tool for managing where the containers are deployed... I think.

Comment: But imagine, we could have imagine, 3 different machines possibly with different operating systems on them which run a given service each. If I want to replicate I just can "Install" the same image in a new machine. However I know that Kubernetes can do this replication process automatically, maybe this is one of the advantages.

Comment: One of the more recent video about Kubernetes and it's advantages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzf9LD1unTk&list=PLlh6TqkU8kg-Sgg--L4SW7wKNtrzJdYpg&index=4 I also suggest watching Kelsey Hightower's presentations, like this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8aUxpVrD40

Comment: Sure, if you have three services and three boxes to run them on, then you can easily administer it all "by hand." But, imagine having hundreds, or thousands, or tens of thousands of servers and services.

Comment: containers use fewer resources than virtual machines but give you slightly less isolation. They are also much faster to bring up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common use case for containers is to help you solve the packaging problem, so that deployment is easier. I'm heavily over-simplifying but I'm hoping to motivate the right ideas:

**Normal:**

- Install dependencies on a machine
- Pull code/binary on the machine & run

**With Docker:**

- Developer puts all the dependencies and the code/binary into a docker image
- Docker image runs anywhere as a container. Is guaranteed to work. No prior machine setup required.

**With Kubernentes**:

- You don't have to manage the action of executing a run container command on a machine inside a cluster of machines.
- As a developer you just create a cluster of machines and tell Kubernetes what container you want to run. Kubernetes figures out the best place to run your container, and runs it and then supervises it for you.

Also, you should really do this course: https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615

Answer (score 1):

1. Containers start up faster than machines
2. Containers are lightweight so the entire image is easier to ship/replicate/backup
3. Containers are standardized, so you can host them on-premises or in the cloud, regardless of whether it is Azure, Google, Amazon, or otherwise
4. Containers improve the development workflow. Instead of installing software, you can simply pull down a container and run it.
5. Containers solve environmental issues. Because all dependencies are shipped in the container, you are never stuck with "worked on my machine but fails on that one".
6. Containers make it easier to roll out upgrades with no downtime. With a cluster of containers, you simply bring up the new version, then bring down the old.
7. Kubernetes makes managing containers at scale easier.
8. Kubernetes helps manage resiliency by understanding the health of a cluster of hosts to run your containers.
9. Kubernetes simplifies access to containers by managing the lifetime for you.